# Modal float out the backdrop without scrollbar

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to design a modal with a backdrop using Tailwind. However, I am encountering a problem where, if my modal becomes larger, the upper part gets cut off and I can't scroll to it, but I can towards the end.

Here is a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/DanBlack123/pen/NWEJrBL)

My Example Code:

```
<div
  class="z-[10000] fixed h-screen w-screen top-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 flex justify-center items-center overflow-auto"
>
  <div class="bg-white overflow-auto w-[44rem] p-4 my-28">
    modal first<br>
    modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>

modal last<br>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried giving the modal "position: sticky; top: 0;" without success.

Comment: You have only set the backdrop element to 100vh height, so you get a scrollbar for that at the right edge of the viewport. You should give `h-screen` to the inner element.

Comment: Please consider accessibility for your modal implementation. I'd recommend using [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog), it's supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Remove `.items-center` it is positioning the child to vertically center

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there may be too many styling classes on the parent element.

Removing the following appears to fix the issue:

- `items-center`
- `fixed`
- `overflow-auto`

Most notable, it seems to be `items-center` causing the problem, it's likely the styling is conflicting.

See the snippet below:
**Note:** Use the fullscreen option as SO's Snippet doesn't provide a large enough window by default.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div class="z-[10000] h-screen w-screen top-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 flex justify-center">
  <div class="bg-white overflow-auto w-[44rem] p-4 my-28">
    modal first<br> modal
    <br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>modal<br>    modal last<br>

  </div>
</div>
```

I would also recommend either:

1. Not using the `z-index` in favour of re-ordering your HTML (see [here](https://www.codegram.com/blog/stop-ab-using-z-index/))
   OR
2. Lowering the `z-index` value